# Second variable in for loop not incrementing

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use two variables `k` and `counter` in a for loop. To be sure that they're actually working, I've made the program print the value of `counter`. However, it just repeatedly prints `0`.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
for (int j : normal_day_in_months) {
    for (int k = 0, counter = 2; k < j; k++, counter++) {
        if (counter == 7) {
            counter = 0;
            cout << counter << endl;
        }
        if (k == 12) {
            day_of_week[counter]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do , but you set counter to 0 then print it, what else do you expect to see

Comment: Wouldn't it continue to increment because the for loop still runs?

Comment: I you don't understand what `counter = 7`  mean, why you use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason this

```
  for (int j : normal_day_in_months) {
        for (int k = 0, counter = 2; k < j; k++, counter++) {
            if (counter == 7) {
                counter = 0; <<<=========== set counter 0
                cout << counter << endl; <<<========== print counter
            }
            if (k == 12) {
                day_of_week[counter]++;
            }
        }
    }
```

prints only zero is because you set counter to 0 then print it. I think maybe you mean this

```
for (int j : normal_day_in_months) {
    for (int k = 0, counter = 2; k < j; k++, counter++) {
        if (counter == 7) {
            counter = 0;
        }
        cout << counter << endl;
        if (k == 12) {
            day_of_week[counter]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Ie print it every time round, whether you set it to 0 or not

Comment: please tick the checkbox on the left of my answer, this indicates that you think its the right answer, useful for others, I get a small bonus too :-)

Comment: I will but I have to wait for around 7 minutes. Don't worry though, I'll make sure to do it :)